# Laravel login using pk key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Sorry for too dummy question, but I can't create session on Laravel using 3 fields to log in. If I using 2 (email and password), auth are successfully. But if I am trying to add third **encrypted** field, I does not have success.

There is my controller part:

```
$email    = Input::get('email');
$password = Input::get('password');
$key      = Crypt::encrypt(Input::get('key'));
$userdata = ['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'key' => $key];

dd(Auth::attempt($userdata)); // false
```

On User model I have two methods to work with **key** field:

```
public function getKeyAttribute($key)
{
    return Crypt::decrypt($key);
}
```

And

```
public function setKeyAttribute($key)
{
    $this->attributes['key'] = Crypt::encrypt($key);
}
```

I have tried all options, but works only without **key**

Comment: I imagine this is happening because your encrypting the key when you pass it to the Auth method. On your model your using an accessor to force Laravel to decrypt the key when it is retrieved from the database. The Auth class needs to retrieve it from the database to compare them. So the Auth method is comparing the encrypted key against the decrypted key, which will resolve as false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely happening as @Jeemusu said. Your class accessor automatically *encrypts* the key you provide when setting the value, so it's basically encriptying it *twice* since you already feed him with a pre-encrypted key.

```
$email    = Input::get('email');
$password = Input::get('password');
$key      = Input::get('key');
$userdata = ['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'key' => $key];
```

Just removing the encryption call should work fine, otherwise you need to remove the `setKeyAttribute()` call (but I'll leave it for coeherency)